# Why do fgets reads my first input in scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

So, when i execute my program it reads one less value than it should, and I think the problem is with the scanf/fgets, but i dont know hot to work it out. Help?

```
 int main(){

int n;
char s[200];

scanf("%i", &n);

for (int i = 0; i<n+1; i++)
{
    if (i==0)
    {
        continue;
    } else if (i >=1) {
        fgets(s, 200, stdin);

        first(s);
        second(s);
        third(s);
        puts(s);
    }
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: what's your sample input?

Comment: Oh cool, another duplicate.

Comment: Likely because scanf() is leaving a newline character in the input buffer.